# Android JAVA: Reading variables that a thread is accessing

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

I've got an app with several screens.  In addition, I have a globally-running timer that occasionally (every minute or so) attempts to refresh their transaction data from a website and store it in a JSONArray (`static JSONArray jTransactions`).

When you go to the Transaction screen, the first thing it does is populate a ListView with the contents of jTransactions, and it will refresh the displayed info every few seconds.  However if the web-thread is currently running, I get null values for everything.

I've got enough coder savvy to know that it's a threading issue, but I'm not experienced enough with JAVA/Android development to know how to handle it.  And my Google-fu may be weak but the only answers I found either didn't apply or involved heavy rewriting.

I guess my question is this - how can I alter my code so that there's no direct collision between my activity and the fetch thread?

Also I fully accept that my code is probably ugly; as I said, I'm still learning the platform.

Here's a pared-down version of the thread I'm running:

```
        static int iRefreshTransactions = 30000;
        static boolean bRefreshingTransactions = false;
        static Calendar cLastRefreshTransactions = null;
        final Runnable mRefreshTransactions = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
               Thread T = new tRefreshTransactions();
               T.start();
           }
        };
        private class tRefreshTransactions extends Thread {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            bRefreshingTransactions = true;
            RetrieveTransactions();
                bRefreshingTransactions = false;
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
            private Handler handler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    cLastRefreshTransactions = Calendar.getInstance();
                    ShowToast("cLastRefreshTransactions(): " + cLastRefreshTransactions.getTime().toLocaleString());
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mRefreshTransactions, iRefreshTransactions);
            }
            };
            private Handler failhandler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    // handle the failure somehow
                }
            };
        }
```

Here's a pared-down version of the RetrieveTransactions() code:

```
    // Retrieve the user's latest transactions from the website.
    public boolean RetrieveTransactions() {
        String result;
        FailureReason = "";
        iTransactions = 0;

        // Retrieve the Page.
        result = GetPage(Url);

        // Strip the transactions from the page and convert them to a JSONArray.
        try {
            String sTransactions = textExtract(result, "var dataTable1Data=", ";\n", 0);
            jTransactions = new JSONArray(sTransactions);
            iTransactions = jTransactions.length();
            return true;
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // Generally if it fails during this, there was no JSONArray to parse (hence no transactions).
            FailureReason = "No Transactions Found";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And finally here's the pared-down code that displays the transactions in a listview, which is called at activity launch and every 5 seconds or so thereafter:

```
public void ShowTransactions() {
    try {
        if (!bRefreshingTransactions) {
            if (iTransactions==0) {
                return;
            } 
            if (iTransactions==0) return;
            List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(iTransactions);
            for (int i = 0; i < iTransactions; i++) {
                listContents.add(jTransactions.getString(iTransactions - i - 1));
            }
            lvRecentTransactions.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapterTransactions(MyContext, listContents));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Do error stuff here
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be mutual exclusion problem. Make `jTransaction` synchronized or put the `jTransaction` variable in `synchonized` block.

```
  synchronized(jTransactions ){
        String sTransactions = textExtract(result, "var dataTable1Data=", ";\n", 0);
        jTransactions = new JSONArray(sTransactions);
        iTransactions = jTransactions.length();
   }
```

I didn't test the code but I hope synchronization will help you.

Comment: Java makes this easy by essentially taking care of mutual exclusion with the synchronized keyword. You can use a block (like Faizan suggested) or you can use it in a method, e.g. public synchronized void threadSafeMethod();

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you for the ++knowledge.  However that opens a new issue - if there's a collision, the app now hangs until it's resolved.  Since I'm retrieving a webpage, this could be up to several seconds while it's waiting for it to finish.  Is there a way to cache the value of jTransactions before fetching so that the ShowTransactions function can use the cached value in the event of a collision?

Comment: EDIT TO ABOVE: If I wrap the sync as you suggested, I still get the same problem (empty values).  If I include the GetPage() line in the sync, it works fine except for the hang.

Comment: COMPLETE AND FINAL EDIT: I found the problem... I was declaring iTransactions = 0 earlier in the function, and that was what was throwing my other function off.  I removed the line and everything seems to work great.  Thank you!